# CSS - Style a line with adjustable columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do the layout of a user registration page in an testing application, and I'm running into trouble putting each component in place. I must say, CSS was never my strong. The design of my form is pretty simple, nothing fancy. Look:

[image]

I can style everything perfectly, the outline of the page, the title, the session for each group of fields provided by the customer. But... My problem is with the layout of the birthday field. I tried to style the user input fields inside a table, more or less following this scheme here:

[image]

In the scheme, I got the part in red as the content of each session (sessions are the green parts). Note that we have a table with two columns and 6 rows separated using the style parameter "border-spacing".

As a final result, the day, month and year fields  (dd/mm/yyyy) always end up staying in different lines, or causing the second column becomes wider horizontally. They end up getting a size which I do not want to. In this type of styling, I am creating a page without a defined width (I am distributing the fields with width "%"), allowing the user to stretch it as desired. **I am also avoiding the use of JavaScript or field type "date"**, which is only compatible with some browsers.

Could someone point me to one or another way to do this kind of layout, or show me what I'm doing wrong?

I appreciate your attention. Thank you.

### EDIT

In the system I'm testing, I am using Java EE (JSP/EL), so I decided to omit the code for simplicity. I changed it a bit so that it remained only in HTML and CSS, and here is a snippet of it:

HTML:

```
<div class="folha">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>SEX</td>
            <td>BIRTHDAY</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="sex" placeholder="sex"/></td>
            <td id="date">
                <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="day"/>
                <span>/</span>
                <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="month"/>
                <span>/</span>
                <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="year"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.folha table,
.folha td
{
    border: 1px black solid;    /* DEBUG */
}

.folha table
{
    width: 92.5%;
    margin: 0px auto;

    border-spacing: 60px 0px;
}

.folha table input[type="text"]
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;

    text-align: center;

    border: 1px red solid;      /* DEBUG */
}

.folha table tr:nth-child(odd) td
{
    padding: 16px 0px;
}

.folha #date input
{
    width: 20%;
}
```

Visually, I am getting the following results (there are 2 in the same image):

[image]

I wish that the fields stay the same the first image of my question, that is, aligned, and stretched properly. I'm not an expert in CSS, so I'm learning to use it. If anyone has any other suggestions of how to do this, I will accept as valid the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edited now that source code is available:

So if you want the two columns to be the same width, you should specify that under **.folha td**.

The date inputs appear to be basing their percentage width off of the width of their parent cell, which means if you set it to 33% or some such, they will loop around to a new line because the three inputs (plus spacers!) no longer fit.

Frankly I do not think it is possible to have the date inputs take up exactly 100% of the space, because the spacers in between them are specified in pixels. If you really want the date inputs to take up exactly 100% of the space, you need to also set the width of the spacers using a percentage.

I would also consider setting a max and min width on the table itself, to avoid unexpected outcomes at extreme browser sizes.

I hope this was helpful :)

Comment: Hi Rosemary. As you suggested, I added a part of the source code. Could you give me any suggestions on how to solve this? Your answer was... not very clear, I guess. Would you mind editing it? I Hope I'm not asking too much. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you get automatic notification of edits, so I just wanted to make sure you knew I'd replied.

Comment: Indeed it was helpful, thank you. Unfortunately, after several tests and trials, I could not leave the date field as I wanted. I had to leave it a little smaller, occupying a space that it could be modified as the user changes the dimensions of the browser. I am grateful for your help and for your patience. Your answer unfortunately did not solve my problem, but in the right, I had better results, thank you. I think maybe what I'm trying is not possible, I do not know.